# Need an EmguCV structure

Tags: opencv, emgucv

Here's the problem. We currently allocate managed memory as a byte[]. Using GCAlloc we pin this array down. As part of this we have to align the pointer we pass to a device driVer on a 4K boundary. The device driver reads the data and deposits into this array. We then process from there. I want to use some of the EmguCV SDK as this is a WPF application.

What I cannot figure out is how to get this data into a Mat or CvArray or other object where I can access it. Could anyone give me an idea how to get this pinned data into an EmguCV/OpenCV object for further processing?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this isn't so bad. I w3as digging through some old emails and came across this:

*If the frame is in memory and you have the pointer, you can directly create an Mat header pointing to the specific memory. It is very efficient and no memory copy will be needed. If your memory pointer point to data in BGR color space, and each pixel is represented in 3 bytes, just do:

```
Mat m = new Mat(imageSize, DepthType.Cv8U, 3, handler.AddrOfPinnedObject(), step);
```

and you will have a Emgu CV Mat that shares the data with the unmanaged code.*

Hope this will help someone else out.

Doug